# Can't convert an API to modal using map and fromjson

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I need to convert a web API to modal. I am using dio for fetch it and here is the fetch output from dio:

```
{
 success: true,
 status: 200,
 message: "Category is ready to show",
 data: [
   {id: 5, name: Pharmacy, img: sub_cat1705749441.png, color: #e5edfa},
   {id: 6, name: Seafood, img: sub_cat1705749543.png, color: #ffeddd}
  ]
}
```

then in repository I use the following code to modal the API fetch:

```
final allSubCatListApi = await homeApi.getSubCatApi();

  var responseJson =
      allSubCatListApi['data'].map((e) => SubCatModal.fromjson(e)).toList();
```

Here is the output:

> Instance of 'SubCatModal', Instance of 'SubCatModal', Instance of 'SubCatModal', Instance of 'SubCatModal']

So, it is modelling well but the type of `responseJson` is still `List<dynamic>` not `List<SubCatModal>`, **so I need to convert the type to be   `List<SubCatModal>`.**

Here is the modal:

```
class SubCatModal {
  late int id;
  late String name;
  late String img;
  late String color;

  SubCatModal.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    img = json['img'];
    color = json['color'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `SubCatModal` as generic type parameter to the `map` method (https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.5/dart-core/Iterable/map.html):

```
List<SubCatModal> responseJson =
      allSubCatListApi['data'].map<SubCatModal>((e) => SubCatModal.fromjson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: no need for such verbose syntax: instead of `map<SubCatModal>((e) => SubCatModal.fromjson(e))` you can just use `map(SubCatModal.fromjson)`

Comment: @pskink Didn't know about this syntax, but dartpad.dev does not seem happy without the generic type parameter. I tried `List<SubCatModal> responseJson = test['data'].map(SubCatModal.fromjson).toList();`. Or was this more in terms of general syntax?

Comment: @pskink Here is the one that does not work for me: https://dartpad.dev/?id=13a838b91266f292a961b5d185c4d6fc. Do you see anything wrong? Maybe because the List that gets map already is `List<dynamic>`?

Comment: yes, it should be `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` so: `(test['data'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>).map(....`

Comment: but actually it should be done with [patterns](https://dart.dev/language/patterns), see: `// with "switch"
      switch (test['data']) {
    case List<Map<String, dynamic>> data:
      final responseJson =
        data.map(SubCatModal.fromjson).toList();
      print(responseJson.runtimeType);
    case _:
      print('wrong data');
  }

  // with "if case"
  if (test['data'] case List<Map<String, dynamic>> data) {
    final responseJson =
      data.map(SubCatModal.fromjson).toList();
    print(responseJson.runtimeType);
  } else {
    print('wrong data');
  }`

Comment: btw, at the very bottom of "patterns" link I gave you there is a similar use case: https://dart.dev/language/patterns#validating-incoming-json